# Why object don't assigned the null

Tags: javascript

How explain behavior this function `clear()` ?
Why object `a` don't assigned the null ?

```
var a = {};
function clear(a) {
  a.b = 2;
  a = null;
}
clear(a);

console.log(a);    // {b: 2}
console.log(a.b);  // 2
```

Comment: This behaviour is called *call by sharing*

Comment: all `a = null` does in the function is point the local variable `a` to a new place -- null. It has no effect on where the outside variable `a` points and has no effect on the object it references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a variable in JavaScript, you are not working with the object itself. You are instead working with a *reference* to the object. Think of variables as signs that point to objects (in other languages like C, these references are appropriately called pointers).

Also, any arguments referenced inside of functions are their own, distinct references. Therefore, assigning these variables to something else while inside the function does not change (mutate) the object that they reference.

For example:

```
var someObject = {a: 1, b:2, c:3};
function doSomething(a) {
    a = null;
}

doSomething(someObject);
console.log(someObject) // {a: 1, b:2, c:3}
```

The only thing that happened inside of the `doSomething` function was that `a` was set to point to `null` rather than `someObject`.

In your example, you have a global variable (variable defined outside of a function) called `a`, and a local function variable also called `a`. If you want the function to change the global `a`, you would have to either remove the argument from `clear`, or change the argument name and still reference `a` inside the `clear` function, like so:

```
var a = {};
function clear() {
    a.b = 2;
    a = null;
}
clear();

console.log(a);    // null
console.log(a.b);  // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'b' of null
```

or

```
var a = {};
function clear(b) {
    a.b = 2;
    a = null;
}
clear(a);          // Note that it does not matter whether you pass a in or not

console.log(a);    // null
console.log(a.b);  // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'b' of null
```

Comment: Thanks so much for detailed explanation!

Answer (score 1):

When you are passing `a` to function `clear`, you pass the copy of the reference to object `a`. So  executing  `a.b = 2;` sets value `b` in object `a`.

But as I have mentioned `a` inside of `clear` function is just a copy of the reference, so setting it to `null` simply says that inside of the `clear` function parameter `a` points to `null`. it does not modify the original a object.